# sequencing jQuery functions with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, callback

I'm getting book info from two different Google Books bookshelves via the API and trying to put it into my custom HTML, but not everything is displaying, and it seems to be because my functions are firing out of sequence, even though I have them laid out in the order I want them and everything is inside $ready. Do I need to use callbacks somehow?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbrLv/

Here is a shot of the console showing the steps firing out of order: http://min.us/mQ0LNVYYT

Comment: Regardless to the specific question, I'd like to ask you about some other things in your code: why do you use `$(function() {..})` construct inside of a getJSON response handler?

Comment: just following an example from somewhere, either from YQL or Google Books API ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), as one of the `$.ajax`-based functions of jQuery, implements the powerful Promise interface. That means you can actually make these calls chained with [$.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) method, by something like this:

```
$.getJSON(myquery, function(data) {
  ... 
}).then(function() {
  $.getJSON(myquery2, function(data) {
     ...
  } 
});
```

UPDATE: Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yNj7/). I'd have to put a quick hack there: pubdateFixer function. You've put it into `$(function(){})` form within the second getJSON handler, but that's not correct: the function should fire exactly after the getJSON content arrives, and not when the initial page gets loaded.

Comment: that sounds simpler. any downside vs the alternative approach below?

Comment: That IS simpler. The only downside I see is that it's slower as the queries won't be done in parallel. Depending on your problem this may be problematic or not (probably not).

Comment: The promises and deferreds in jQuery are truly powerful. You could also start up multiple asynchronous requests and specify a callback to execute when they *all* complete using [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). This could be helpful if you need to fetch data from multiple sources and display them as soon as all data has been retrieved.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling asynchronous functions.

You can't at all predict the order in which the responses will come from the server and your callback will be called (yes, you're yet using callbacks, as `$.getJSON` takes a callback as last argument).

So, if you need to ensure a specific order of response handling, you need to either use the jquery [then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) function (first referenced by raina77ow) to chain the calls, or add another guarding mechanism, for example a boolean for each response and a few lines of code ensuring you do the operations in the desired order.

For example :

```
function bigOperationNeedingBothAnswers() {
}

var answersStillNotArrived=2; 


$.getJSON(firstQuery, function (data) {
   // some things
   if (--answersStillNotArrived==0) bigOperationNeedingBothAnswers();
}
$.getJSON(otherQuery, function (data) {
   // some things
   if (--answersStillNotArrived==0) bigOperationNeedingBothAnswers();
}
```

Comment: ok, i'm not much of a coder and would love an example of a boolean for a response..